# Timeline Portfolio + modal

Tags: jquery, json, popup, modal-dialog, timeline.js

I looking to add a modal script in the timeline script like Timeline Portfolio from timeline JS. The script use json for the data base. And I don't know how to merge the link to start the modal popup.

Exemple popup used:

> Link to open the popup
> `<a href="#popup1" data-width="500" data-rel="popup1" class="poplight">Try</a>`
> Content Popup:
>   `<div id="popup1" class="popup_block">`
>       `<h2>Popup</h2>`
>       `<p>Test</p>`
>   `</div>`

Exemple base json from timeline:

> `{`
>       `"timeline":`
>       `{`
>           `"headline":"TimeLine",`
>           `"type":"default"`,
>           `"startDate":"2000,6",`
>           `"text":"<a href='#popup1' data-width='500' data-rel='popup1' class='poplight'>Try</a>",`
>           `"asset":`
>           `{`
>              `"media":"",`
>               `"credit":""`,
>               `"caption":""`
>           `}`
>           `]`
>       `}`
>   `}`

I think the json file don't share information, or order with my html page or jquery script.

You know if it's possible to allow this action ?

thanks in advance for your point of view,
BR,
Bruno

Comment: What is the purpose?
Anyhow, according to the Timeline.js documentation (http://timeline.knightlab.com/): "You can include a link in the text field using the standard HTML for a hyperlink." Thereby you probably can't use data-* which is new with HTML5. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)